# Check for multiple open port

Tags: c#, sockets, port

I have this program whereby i'll need to check port availability (port 11000 and port 1883) .

I did test it in two scenario :

(1).I started up a server(using port 11000) and MQTT broker(using port 1883) were . 
Results were both button14 and button 15 changed to AQUA color .

(2).I shutdown both server and mqtt broker+service . Results were both button14 and button15 changed to AQUA color .

My question , wasn't both button14 & button15 supposedly changed to RED?

```
private void checkPort(int serialPortNum, int mqttPortNum)
    {
        TcpConnectionInformation[] tcpConnInfoArray = ipGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections();
        bool isAvailable = true;

        //check for socket 11000
        foreach (TcpConnectionInformation tcpi in tcpConnInfoArray)
        {
            if (tcpi.LocalEndPoint.Port == serialPortNum)
            {
                button14.BackColor = Color.Red;
                isAvailable = false;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("" + isAvailable);
                isAvailable = true;
                button15.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
                break;
            }

        }

        //check for socket 11000
        foreach (TcpConnectionInformation tcpi in tcpConnInfoArray)
        {
            if (tcpi.LocalEndPoint.Port == mqttPortNum)
            {

                isAvailable = false;
                button14.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("" + isAvailable);
                isAvailable = true;
                button14.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
                break;
            }

        }



        MessageBox.Show("Port availability is :" + isAvailable);
```

Comment: What is means is mqttPortNum is not the first port number in the array TcpConnectionInformation[]

Comment: hi @jdweng , is there any way you would suggest of how can I achieve this ?

Comment: I would put a break point an check the values of tcpConnInfoArray to see if the port number(s) are correct.

Comment: can you suggest in programmatical way? @jdweng

Comment: I don't usually write code for simple debugging.  Adding break points and hovering over variable gives me a lot more info about a structure then just outputting one property of a structure.  In your case the color will be the first port number in the array.  So if you have ports 10001, 10002, 10003  you are breaking out of the loop on first port.  So I would remove the break in the "else".  I would also set the button to Aqua before getting into for loop in case there is no mqttPortNum and the button is already red.  And then the else is not needed.